# How to test espresso android native components provied by sdk e.g. android:id/search_close_btn

Tags: android, android-espresso

Tests where we use android native search components in the AppBar but Espresso not able to access these from resourcse. e.g android.R.id.search_close_btn not found. Any idea how to be tested?

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.search_close_btn)).perform(click));
```

or

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.search_src_text)).perform(click));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onView(withText("Clear query")).perform(click));`, this will search for the view with content description.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes view doesn't have any text or id, but it has a content description like "Press back". In that case you can use `withContentDescription()` Espresso matcher like in that exapmple:

`onView(withContentDescription("Press back")).perform(click());`